# i'm in a catch 22 situation vs i have a catch 22 situation

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Two people were conversing in something I read (I forget the details)

> — I'm caught in a catch 22 situation..."
>   —"I have a catch 22 situation myself, and it's going to be the reason I die early."

Here, the speaker is talking about his being in a tough situation which could lead to his early death. The thing that bothers me is, I have never heard anyone say **I have a catch-22 situation**. Usually, it's "**it's a catch 22 (situation)**" or "**I'm in a catch-22 situation**". 
So, is it grammatically correct to say **I have a catch-22 situation**, to convey the meaning that **I am in a catch-22 situation**?

Comment: Sure,it's fine.

Comment: Take care with the spelling of "I" or "I'm" they are always written with a capital.  Also what is the source of the quote? Please tell us who the speaker is.

Comment: @JamesK I forgot where I read it. Basically, two people were conversing and one of them went "i'm caught in a catch 22 situation...", and the other guy responded "i have a catch 22 situation myself..."

Comment: @JamesK Done, and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatically correct, and while it is less common than "I'm in a Catch-22 situation", it is understandable and correct.

Note that, if used properly, a "Catch-22" situation is not just a difficult situation but specifically "A situation a person cannot escape from because of mutually conflicting conditions". In the original book it was "To escape from the war you had to prove yourself insane, but by asking to escape the war on the grounds of insanity was evidence that you were a rational person and so not insane."